# PHP Form submitting to MySQL whether validation conditions are met or not

Tags: php, forms, validation, form-submit

My php self-validating form is submitting to sql database whether the characters entered into form fields are appropriate or not...How do stop it from submitting until the conditions for each form field are met?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>RSG Contact Us</title>
     <script>
       //            $(function () {
       //     $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
           //   $.ajax({
            //     type: 'post',
            //     url: 'contact.php',
            //     data: $('form').serialize(),
            //           success: function () {
                   //   alert('Thank you! your form has been submitted');
                   //      }
            //          });
           //    e.preventDefault();
           //   });
                   //   });
      </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      <div id="contactuscall">
       <?php
         function test_input($data)
        {
         $data = trim($data);
         $data = stripslashes($data);
         $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
         return $data;
        }

       // define variables and set to empty values
      $firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $emailErr = $cellphoneErr = $genDerErr = $dognameErr = $BreedErr = $reasonErr = "";
      $firstname = $lastname = $email = $cellphone = $genDer = $dogname = $Breed = $reasoN= $freecomments = "";

       //if conditional statement stops PHP from looking for variable values until the submit button is hit
       if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
       {
        // check if a first name was provided
       if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
       {$firstnameErr = "A first name is required";} 
        else 
       {
       $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
       // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
         {$firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";}
       } 
      //check if a last name was provided
      if (empty($_POST["lastname"]))
      {$lastnameErr = "A last name is required";}
      else
      {
      $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
      // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lastname))
        {
        $lastnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
        }
      }
      // check if an email was provided
     if (empty($_POST["email"]))
      {$emailErr = "Email is required";}
      else
      {
      $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      // check if e-mail address syntax is valid
      if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",$email))
        {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
        }
      } 

      if (empty($_POST["cellphone"]))
      {$cellphoneErr = "Please provide a phone number";} 
      else {
       $cellphone = test_input($_POST["cellphone"]);
       // Regular Expression to allow only valid phone number formats, including numbers, spaces, dashes, extensions
       if (!preg_match("/^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$/",$cellphone))
         {$cellphoneErr = "Invalid format";}
        } 

        if (empty($_POST["dogname"]))
        {$dognameErr = "A doggy name is required";} 
        else {
        $dogname = test_input($_POST["dogname"]);
        // check if dogname only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$dogname))
        {$dognameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";}
         } 

        if (empty($_POST["Breed"]))
        {$BreedErr = "A breed name is required";} 
        else {
        $Breed = test_input($_POST["Breed"]);
        // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
        if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$Breed))
         {$BreedErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";}
        } 

        if(empty($_POST['genDer'])) 
        {$genDerErr= "You forgot to select a Gender!";}
        else {
         $genDer=($_POST['genDer']);
         }

        //make sure one of the services requested checkboxes are checked
        $reasoN = $_POST['reasoN'];
        if(empty($reasoN)) 
         {
        $reasonErr="You didn't select any services.";
         } 
       else
        {
       $N = count($reasoN);
        $reasonErr="You selected $N services(s): "; 
        }

       // if comment section is not empty then run test_input function to purge possible malicious code 
       if (empty($_POST["freecomments"]))
        {$freecomments = "";}
        else
       {$freecomments = test_input($_POST["freecomments"]);}
        }  

       $host="fdb3.biz.nf"; //localhost
       $dbuser="1546259_rsginfo"; //user
       $dbpass="RSGnow12"; //pass
       $dbname="1546259_rsginfo"; //db name

    // Create connection
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);  


// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
//create query
$sql= "INSERT INTO customer (fname, lname, email, phone, comments)VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$cellphone', '$freecomments')";
$sql2= "INSERT INTO DogInfo (DogName, Breed, Lookingfor)VALUES ('$dogname', '$Breed', '$reasoN')";

// execute query
mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

// close connection
mysqli_close($conn)   
?>
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <fieldset id="field1">
      <legend id="legend1">Contact info:</legend>
      <hr />
        First name: <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" size="30" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $firstname;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $firstnameErr;?></span>
        E-mail: <input type="text" size="30" name="email" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $email;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span><br />
        Last name: <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" size="30" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $lastname;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $lastnameErr;?></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        Cell: <input type="text" id="cellphone"  name="cellphone" size="30" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $cellphone;?>">
      <span class="error">* <?php echo $cellphoneErr;?></span><br />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field2">
      <legend id="legend2">Doggie info:</legend>
        <hr />
      Name: <input type="text" id="dogname" name="dogname" size="20" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $dogname;?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $dognameErr;?></span>
      Breed: <input type="text" id="Breed" name="Breed" size="20" class="textfield" value="<?php echo $Breed;?>"><span class="error">* <?php echo $BreedErr;?></span>
    <p>
        Gender:<select name="genDer" class="textfield">
             <option value="">--</option>
             <option  value="Intact Male" <?php echo isset($_POST['genDer']) && $_POST['genDer'] == "Intact Male" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Intact Male</option>
             <option  value="Neutered Male"<?php echo isset($_POST['genDer']) && $_POST['genDer'] == "Neutered Male" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Neutered Male</option>
             <option  value="Intact Female"<?php echo isset($_POST['genDer']) && $_POST['genDer'] == "Intact Female" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Intact Female</option>
             <option  value="Neutered Female"<?php echo isset($_POST['genDer']) && $_POST['genDer'] == "Neutered Female" ? "selected" : "" ?>>Neutered Female</option>
          </select><span class="error">* <?php echo $genDerErr;?></span>
     </p>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field3">
      <legend id="legend3">Services Required:</legend>
      <hr />
      <input type="checkbox" name="reasoN[]" value="walkSale"
      <?php if(isset($_POST['reasoN'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking for a Dog Walker!&nbsp;

      <input type="checkbox" name="reasoN[]" value="RawSale"
      <?php if(isset($_POST['reasoN'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking to purchase Raw Food!&nbsp;

      <input type="checkbox" name="reasoN[]" value="groomSale"
      <?php if(isset($_POST['reasoN'])) echo "checked='checked'";?> class="textfield"/>I'm looking for a Dog Groomer!

      <span class="error">* <?php echo $reasonErr;?></span>
         <?php echo $reasonConfirm;?>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id="field4">
      <legend id="legend4">Comments &amp; Questions</legend>
      <hr />
      <textarea rows="7" cols="90" id="freecomments" name="freecomments"><?php echo $freecomments;?></textarea>
    </fieldset>
      <input id="submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
   </form>
  </div>
<?php 
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $firstname;
echo "<br>";
echo $lastname;
echo "<br>";
echo $email;
echo "<br>";
echo $cellphone;
echo "<br>";
echo $dogname;
echo "<br>";
echo $Breed;
echo "<br>";   
echo $genDer;
echo "<br>";
echo $reasoN;
echo "<br>";   
echo $freecomments;
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove all of your if statements that are validating each submitted post value.  Change them to simply assigning the values to variables without the `if`.

Comment: You should be placing a condition => `if(all are not empty and/or valid ){ // execute SQL }` *in a nutshell*. You don't have one (condition) wrapping your SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code actually tries to insert values in to the table whether or not the validation is successful. The easiest and the quickest solution for this is to use a boolean flag.

eg:

```
// ... 
$formValid = true; // Define a boolean and set to true before validating

//if conditional statement stops PHP from looking for variable values until the submit button is hit
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
    // check if a first name was provided
   if (empty($_POST["firstname"]))
   {
       $firstnameErr = "A first name is required";
   } else {
       $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
       // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
       if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$firstname))
       {
           $firstnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
           $formValid = false; // Invalid input - set the flag to false
       }
   } 
}
// ....

// Eventually wrap the mysql logic inside a condition
 if ($formValid)
 {
    // Create connection
    $conn=mysqli_connect($host,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);  


    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($conn))
        {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
    //create query
    $sql= "INSERT INTO customer (fname, lname, email, phone, comments)VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', '$cellphone', '$freecomments')";
    $sql2= "INSERT INTO DogInfo (DogName, Breed, Lookingfor)VALUES ('$dogname', '$Breed', '$reasoN')";

    // execute query
    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
// ... rest of your code
```

Comment: cool, so i have to add the false flag to each validation conditional statement, right?